# Get data from one sheet to other based on one cell status in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheet with data, i want to get data in other sheet but with conditions. This is what my source data looks like:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Cell A   | Cell B |  Cell C    | Cell D|Cell E |        
|------------------------------------------------|
| Sku      |Order_ID|Customer_ID | Price |Status | 
|------------------------------------------------|
| TW22     |   123  |    1       |221    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| TS44     |  124   |     2      |221    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11-ab  |   33   |     3      |211    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11     |   231  |     4      |231    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11-ab  |   33   |     3      |211    |   R   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11     |   231  |     4      |231    |   R   |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

If there are two rows with the same order ID I want to remove the first row (with status D) and only keep the second row (status R). The desired output for the above data would be:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Cell A   | Cell B |  Cell C    | Cell D|Cell E |        
|------------------------------------------------|
| Sku      |Order_ID|Customer_ID | Price |Status | 
|------------------------------------------------|
| TW22     |   123  |    1       |221    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| TS44     |  124   |     2      |221    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11-ab  |   33   |     3      |211    |   R   | 
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11     |   231  |     4      |231    |   R   |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

This is the formula I tried:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!E$2:E$5,(MATCH($B2,Sheet1!B$2:B$5,0)))‌​,-1)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It sounds like this could be done by just removing duplicates.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct i tried vba and vlookup formulas . removing duplicates  tool i used but not get result what i want if i remove duplicates the "R" value data remove but i need that data . can you explain if their is any way to do this thing work as i need . thanks

Comment: vote down is not answer of any question . anyways if someone think its not a question which ask on this site can vote down .

Comment: The downvote is because you did not provide anything that you already tried. Asking for code without showing initiative is generally not well received. If you tried VBA, show what you tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct i found many code and formulas on net . below is which one i will try . formula =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!E$2:E$5,(MATCH($B2,Sheet1!B$2:B$5,0))),-1)  vba code is too long to post here 
`

Comment: That's why you would edit the code into your question. It's good that you posted the solution that you found.

Answer (score 0):

got answer from aditya .. thanks  here is what he provide

```
Sub copy_sheet()

Dim raw_data, new_data As Worksheet

Set raw_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("raw_data")
Set new_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("new_data")

raw_data.Activate
Range("A1:E1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
new_data.Activate
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("A1").Sort key1:=Range("E1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
Range("A1:E1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes
Range("A1").Sort key1:=Range("E1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
Range("A1").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: It's very good that you found your own solution and posted it here. There are a few things you can improve in this solution. There are some pointers in the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=20160929083602128133)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you have already tried, but as I understand it the row with "R" always comes after the row with "D", right? You could go through your table in reverse order and remember all rows with an R. In pseudo code something like:

```
size = yourTable.Rows.Count
Dim col As New Collection
For column = size To 1 Step -1
    If StatusOfCurrentRow = "R" Then
         Copy Row to Sheet2
         col.Add Value of Sku
    Else
         If SkuOfCurrentRow not in col
             Copy Row to Sheet2              
         End If
    End If
Next
```